# bar chart using pure css how to add text out of the main div

Tags: html, css

I created basic bar chart using pure CSS.
[image]

**In the y axis** I want to number it from 0 to 100 incremented by 10.
(0,10,20,30,40,...100)

**In the x axis** I want to name each color bar (Red,Blue,green)
How do I do this using **pure CSS**.
This is my code.

```
<div id="main">
      <div style="background-color:red;" id="bar">

      </div>
      <div style="background-color:blue;" id="bar"></div>
      <div style="background-color:green;" id="bar"></div>

      </div>

<style lang="css">
#main{
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    border-left:5px solid black;
    border-bottom:5px solid black;
    margin:50px;
}
#bar{
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:25px;
    display:inline-block;

}

</style>
```

**How do I achieve this using pure CSS**

Comment: Do You realize that html is for entering content that should be shown (like text "green", "red", "blue" or "10,20,30,..") and CSS is only for the styling? This should be handled via JS or HTML. Surely, there are options how to do that in CSS, but it is **not reasonable** to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sample.
I used pure CSS `:after` for the X axis and created some `HTML` for the Y

```css
.main {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.scaleX {
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  bottom: -25px;
}
.scaleX p {
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.bar:after {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
#red {
  background-color:red;
}
#red:after {
  content:"red";
}
#blue {
  background-color:blue;
}
#blue:after {
  content:"blue";
}
#green {
  background-color:green;
}
#green:after {
  content:"green";
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="scaleX">
    <p>100</p>
    <p>90</p>
    <p>80</p>
    <p>70</p>
    <p>60</p>
    <p>50</p>
    <p>40</p>
    <p>30</p>
    <p>20</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>0</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bar" id="red"></div>
  <div class="bar" id="blue"></div>
  <div class="bar" id="green"></div>
</div>
```